# batch file regex ids from html file

Tags: html, batch-file

I always do manually define list of IDs in list.txt file and creating a long string.
I want create same long string but to parse a html file and export IDs from links inside.

Note: number of IDs in list.txt or list.html can be different

// list.txt

```
450814997
463939057
```

// list.bat

```
set "my_directory=c:\server"
set "list="
for /F "tokens=*" %%A IN ('Type "list.txt"') do (
    set "list=!list!%my_directory%\%%A;"
)
echo %list%
```

// list.html

```
  <body>
    <div class="mod-list">
      <table>
        <tr data-type="ModContainer">
          <td data-type="DisplayName">CBA_A3</td>
          <td>
            <span class="from-steam">Steam</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=450814997" data-type="Link">https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=450814997</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-type="ModContainer">
          <td data-type="DisplayName">ace</td>
          <td>
            <span class="from-steam">Steam</span>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=463939057" data-type="Link">https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=463939057</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="dlc-list">
      <table />
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <span>Created by Arma 3 Launcher by Bohemia Interactive.</span>
    </div>
  </body>
```

expected output:

```
c:\server\450814997;c:\server\463939057;
```

Comment: Your batch, as posted and assuming that you have invoked `delayedexpansion` should output `c:\server\450814997;c:\server\463939057;`

Comment: If your html file does not form part of your question, please [Edit] your post to remove it and its references. If it does please add sufficient information to explain its relevance to your specific problem.

Comment: @Compo I posted html file as reference, what the structure looks like to get relevant ids from.

Comment: So as it has no bearing whatsoever on your question, I've removed it. If you wanted help with some code which takes the ID's directly from the html file instead of from the txt file, you should have posted your code attempt. This is not a free code writing service, where you post code which does something else, and we change it for you.

Comment: Restating the question: This is how I've done it using `list.txt`. How do I do it using `list.html`?

Comment: Sorry @Magoo, but that is off topic. They already know how to join them on one line, so the question would be how do I parse my `list.html` to retrieve the `id`'s directly from the `Link`s. And the comment, not answer, should have been, "you could  use a `for /f` loop with the appropriate `tokens` and `delims`. There are many examples already on this site. However parsing HTML using pure batch file commands is not recommended, you shoold instead consider doing that using PowerShell".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
set "my_directory=c:\server"
set "list="
for /F "tokens=3delims=?" %%E IN ('Type "q77047266.txt"') do (
 SET "token3=%%E"
 IF DEFINED token3 set "list=!list!%my_directory%\!token3:~3,-4!;"
)
echo %list%

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q77047266.txt` containing your HTML data for my testing.

You don't specify whether the required string should be extracted from its first or second occurrence on the line. I chose the last.

Using `?` as a delimiter, grab the part of the line after the second `?` (token3) then append the result to `list`,with the decoration but wiyjout the first 3 characters (id=) and last 3 characters ()

Answer (score 0):

> *I want create same long string but to parse a html file and export IDs from links inside.*

Doing a quick search, that HTML is from https://atwar.online/arma/Arma_3_Preset_hoggit_no_jsrs.html, right?

To parse this HTML-source I'd highly recommend the XML/HTML/JSON parser [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel).

First the two `<tr>`-nodes you're after:

```bash
xidel -s "https://atwar.online/arma/Arma_3_Preset_hoggit_no_jsrs.html"^
      -e "//table/tbody/tr[td[@data-type='DisplayName']=('CBA_A3','ace')]"^
      --output-node-format=xml --output-node-indent
<tr data-type="ModContainer">
  <td data-type="DisplayName">CBA_A3</td>
  <td>
    <span class="from-steam">Steam</span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <a href="http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=450814997" data-type="Link">http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=450814997</a>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr data-type="ModContainer">
  <td data-type="DisplayName">ace</td>
  <td>
    <span class="from-steam">Steam</span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <a href="http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=463939057" data-type="Link">http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=463939057</a>
  </td>
</tr>

xidel -s "https://atwar.online/arma/Arma_3_Preset_hoggit_no_jsrs.html"^
      -e "//table/tbody/tr[td[@data-type='DisplayName']=('CBA_A3','ace')]/td/a/@href"
http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=450814997
http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=463939057
```

Next you can use [`request-decode()`](https://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/xpath-functions.html#x-request-decode) to retrieve the ids:

```bash
xidel -s "https://atwar.online/arma/Arma_3_Preset_hoggit_no_jsrs.html"^
      -e "//table/tbody/tr[td[@data-type='DisplayName']=('CBA_A3','ace')]/td/a/request-decode(@href)"
{
  "url": "http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=450814997",
  "protocol": "http",
  "host": "steamcommunity.com",
  "path": "sharedfiles/filedetails/",
  "query": "id=450814997",
  "params": {
    "id": "450814997"
  }
}
{
  "url": "http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=463939057",
  "protocol": "http",
  "host": "steamcommunity.com",
  "path": "sharedfiles/filedetails/",
  "query": "id=463939057",
  "params": {
    "id": "463939057"
  }
}

xidel -s "https://atwar.online/arma/Arma_3_Preset_hoggit_no_jsrs.html"^
      -e "//table/tbody/tr[td[@data-type='DisplayName']=('CBA_A3','ace')]/td/a/request-decode(@href)/params/id"
450814997
463939057
```

Then it's just a matter of creating the specific string you want. You can do this with `concat()` of course, or with [XPath 4.0 String Templates](https://qt4cg.org/specifications/xquery-40/xpath-40.html#id-string-templates) (provided you're using an up-to-date Xidel binary):

```bash
xidel -s "https://atwar.online/arma/Arma_3_Preset_hoggit_no_jsrs.html"^
      -e "//table/tbody/tr[td[@data-type='DisplayName']=('CBA_A3','ace')]/td/a/request-decode(@href)/params/concat('c:\server\',id,';')"
#or
xidel -s "https://atwar.online/arma/Arma_3_Preset_hoggit_no_jsrs.html"^
      -e "//table/tbody/tr[td[@data-type='DisplayName']=('CBA_A3','ace')]/td/a/request-decode(@href)/params/`c:\server\{id};`"
c:\server\450814997;
c:\server\463939057;
```

And finally `string-join()` or `--output-separator=''` to put everything on a single line:

```bash
xidel -s "https://atwar.online/arma/Arma_3_Preset_hoggit_no_jsrs.html"^
      -e "string-join(//table/tbody/tr[td[@data-type='DisplayName']=('CBA_A3','ace')]/td/a/request-decode(@href)/params/`c:\server\{id};`)"
#or
xidel -s "https://atwar.online/arma/Arma_3_Preset_hoggit_no_jsrs.html"^
      -e "//table/tbody/tr[td[@data-type='DisplayName']=('CBA_A3','ace')]/td/a/request-decode(@href)/params/`c:\server\{id};`"^
      --output-separator=''
c:\server\450814997;c:\server\463939057;
```

If you want all ids, then simply remove the condition (between `[` `]`):

```bash
xidel -s "https://atwar.online/arma/Arma_3_Preset_hoggit_no_jsrs.html"^
      -e "//table/tbody/tr/td/a/request-decode(@href)/params/`c:\server\{id};`"^
      --output-separator=''
```